Finding Peaks in a 2D Matrix in MATLAB
The nature of my data is something like this:

As you can see it has a lot of peaks and my data is very noisy as well. Now the peaks can be these wall-like structures running along X or Y axis.
Currently, I am using a very naive approach:

Find all local maxima
Find a threshold by taking an average of all local maxima
Classify the peaks as significant only if they cross the threshold

I want to use a more efficient algorithm for this. Can anybody point me in the right direction?
After much research, I found that persistent homology can be applied to my issue. But again, I don't have much knowledge on the topic, so any help is appreciated.

hello Sweta, any chance to read your code mentioned in your question ?

You might be able to implement something more efficient using a couple of recent additions to MATLAB:

smoothdata2 has various options for pre-processing your data to remove noise. New in R2023b.
islocalmax2 can then find the local maxima, with a number of options as to how to find them. New in R2024a.


I am aware of these new options and tried them on my dataset as well. But since my data is huge (something like 40000*125 elements). These inbuilt features don't really work for me. Takes a long time and hangs often.
